How to configure Bazel/Google Test to resolve `bazel test` linker error
I have started a new C++ project and I'm trying to configure Bazel and Google Test.
Bazel is configured to build the core project as a DLL. The DLL builds fine, and I can also build an exe which depends on the DLL. Google's sample tests run fine as they don't reference the library, but when a test links a library header I get linker errors like this:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl CallbackLogger::registerLogInfo(void (__cdecl*)(char const *,int))" (?registerLogInfo@CallbackLogger@@QEAAXP6AXPEBDH@Z@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __cdecl CallbackLoggerTest_RegisterLogInfoCallback_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@CallbackLoggerTest_RegisterLogInfoCallback_Test@@EEAAXXZ)

My project has this structure:
src
  WORKSPACE
  MODULE.bazel
  core
    ... some other files/folders
    logger
      callback_logger.h
      callback_logger.cpp
    windows_dll_library.bzl
    BUILD
  test
    BUILD
    callback_logger_test.cpp

The test code:
/test/callback_logger_test.cpp
#include "../core/logger/callback_logger.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test_callback(const char *message, int size)
{
    string str(message, size);
    cout << "Message received: " + str << endl;
}

// Tests registering loginfo callback
TEST(CallbackLoggerTest, RegisterLogInfoCallback)
{
    auto logger = new CallbackLogger();
    logger->registerLogInfo(&test_callback);
}

And these are my BUILD files:
/core/BUILD:
load(":windows_dll_library.bzl", "windows_dll_library")

# Define the shared library
windows_dll_library(
    name = "core",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
    # Define COMPILING_DLL to export symbols during compiling the DLL.
    copts = ["/DCOMPILING_DLL"],
    visibility = ["//test:__pkg__", "//core_runner:__pkg__"],
)

/test/BUILD:
cc_test(
    name = "test",
    size = "small",
    srcs = glob(["*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
        "//core:core",
    ],
)

I'm running the tests with this Bazel command:
bazel test --test_output=all //test:test
How do I configure Bazel to link the library?
Extra info
Here is the bazel config for the windows DLL library:
windows_dll_library.bzl
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_import", "cc_library")

def windows_dll_library(
        name,
        srcs = [],
        deps = [],
        hdrs = [],
        visibility = None,
        **kwargs):
    """A simple windows_dll_library rule for builing a DLL Windows."""
    dll_name = name + ".dll"
    import_lib_name = name + "_import_lib"
    import_target_name = name + "_dll_import"

    # Build the shared library
    cc_binary(
        name = dll_name,
        srcs = srcs + hdrs,
        deps = deps,
        linkshared = 1,
        **kwargs
    )

    # Get the import library for the dll
    native.filegroup(
        name = import_lib_name,
        srcs = [":" + dll_name],
        output_group = "interface_library",
    )

    # Because we cannot directly depend on cc_binary from other cc rules in deps attribute,
    # we use cc_import as a bridge to depend on the dll.
    cc_import(
        name = import_target_name,
        interface_library = ":" + import_lib_name,
        shared_library = ":" + dll_name,
    )

    # Create a new cc_library to also include the headers needed for the shared library
    cc_library(
        name = name,
        hdrs = hdrs,
        visibility = visibility,
        deps = deps + [
            ":" + import_target_name,
        ],
    )

This is a standard file that was provided in a Bazel sample.
If I add the DLL package (//core:core) to deps when building an exe, this is all I need to do:
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "my_exe",
    srcs = ["my_exe.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//core:core",
    ],
)

my_exe can now call the exported functions in the DLL.
But for my unit tests I want to exercise the classes within the library, not just the DLL's external interface.
How do I configure Bazel to do this? Do I need to provide another library config in BUILD for the DLL package to be available as a static library too?

glob(["*.cpp"]) - don't do that. List required files explicitly. We need a [mre]. I can guess you don't dll-import CallbackLogger properly.

@3CxEZiVlQ You are correct. I want to test the internal code which isn't exported in the dll usually, so I've extracted this functionality into a static library which the dll package and the test package can link.

The problem is caused by my tests trying to access functions which aren't exported in the dll.
The exported dll functions are prefixed with __declspec(dllexport), and only these functions can be called on the dll. Because I want to unit test the library's internal classes, but I don't want to export this internal functionality in the dll, I need to split the core functionality into a static library and make the dll a wrapper for this static library. The test package can link the static library directly, and the dll only needs to export the necessary functions.
This gives a project structure like this:
src
  WORKSPACE
  MODULE.bazel
  api
    api.h
    api.cpp
    windows_dll_library.bzl
    BUILD
  core
    ... other files/folders
    logger
      callback_logger.h
      callback_logger.cpp
    BUILD
  test
    BUILD
    callback_logger_test.cpp

Giving 3 packages which can be built:

//core:core. This is the static library which contains the bulk of the library code.
//api:api. This produces the DLL and only exports the functions marked __declspec(dllexport). Depends on //core:core.
//test:test. This is the test package which exercises the core functionality. Depends on //core:core.

Here are the new BUILD files:
/core/BUILD
cc_library(
    name = "core",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
    visibility = [
        "//api:__pkg__",
        "//test:__pkg__",
    ],
)

/api/BUILD
load(":windows_dll_library.bzl", "windows_dll_library")

# Define the shared library
windows_dll_library(
    name = "api",
    srcs = ["api.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["api.h"],
    deps = ["//core:core"],
    # Define COMPILING_DLL to export symbols during compiling the DLL.
    # See api.h
    copts = ["/DCOMPILING_DLL"],
)

test/BUILD
cc_test(
    name = "test",
    size = "small",
    srcs = glob(["*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
        "//core:core",
    ],
)

